# Asp.Net MVC 5 Fill EditorFor When Dropdown SelectedItem Changed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, editorfor

I need to fill Html.EditorFor controls when I select an product from Dropdown. I am very newbie at JQuery and Ajax.

**My Dropdown:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", 
@onchange= "FillPrice()", id= "ProductId" })
```

**EditorFor:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductPrice, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new { 
                           @class = "form-control",  
                           id="txtPrice" } })
```

**Javascript:**

```
function FillPrice() {
    var ProductId = $('#ProductId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPrice")',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { ProductId: ProductId },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (price) {
            $('#txtPrice').val()   ??? What to write here to fill txtPrice?
        }
    });  
  }
```

**Controller/GetPrice:**

```
public JsonResult GetPrice(int ProductId)
{
    var price = from r in db.Products
                where r.Id == ProductId
                select new { 
                     id = r.Id, 
                     label = r.ProductPrice, 
                     value = r.ProductPrice };
    return Json(price, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Up to this point, everything works. I check with Firebug and see the Json get and results but I can't bind the value to the EditorFor.

Comment: `$('#txtPrice').val(price.value)` - but why are you returning 2 properties (`label` and `value`) with the same value? You can also delete the `contentType:` option

Comment: Add: `success: function (price) { console.dir(price); ` and have a look at what properties `price` has.

Comment: I deleted contentType block and also label= r.ProductPrice properties. Then I tried '$('#txtPrice').val(price.value)' but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response in your JavaScript is in the `price` variable:

```
function (price) {
    //...
}
```

Based on the server-side code, it looks like that object has three values:

```
new { 
    id = r.Id, 
    label = r.ProductPrice, 
    value = r.ProductPrice }
```

(I'm not sure why you need the same value twice, but whatever.)

So you're probably looking for the `value` property of that variable?:

```
$('#txtPrice').val(price.value);
```

You can also check your browser's debugger and see the structure of the `price` variable to make sure.

---

**Edit:** It looks like the return value may be an array.  Which makes sense given that the server-side code is resulting in an `IEnumerable<>`.  If it *should* only be returning a single value, you might make that explicit.  Something like this:

```
return Json(price.Single(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You'll want to add some error checking around that, and the logic for handling errors (multiple found values or no found value) is up to you.

Conversely, if you want it to be an array, you would access it as an array client-side:

```
$('#txtPrice').val(price[0].value);
```

Again, you'd want to add some error checking (in the client-side code this time) to make sure a value exists before trying to use it.

Comment: With Google Chrome Debugger, on Network tab I see that result: [{id: 14, value: 24}]. But $('#txtPrice').val(price.value); doesn't give me the value: 24

Comment: @degergio: According to that debugger output, it looks like `price` is an array.  Try: `price[0].value` instead.  Though you may want to change the server-side code to return a single value if you're only expecting a single value.

Comment: Oh, thank you. That worked for me. $('#txtPrice').val(price[0].value); gave me the result. If you edit your answer, I will mark as answer to help others.

Comment: @degergio: Answer is now updated with a couple of options.  I recommend modifying the server-side code accordingly so that the API exposes what you expect it to.  But it's up to you and how you want to structure your API (and where you want to encapsulate any error checking and defensive programming).

Comment: When defining the Product, Price is Required and Dropdown populate with only the existing Products. So there is no chance to be null or empty response if you select the product from this Dropdown.

Comment: @degergio: There is *little* chance, but there is *a* chance.  Even from perhaps an error in the logic elsewhere on the consuming page.  A well-handled error makes debugging easier.

Comment: May I add 2 $.ajax for FillPrice() functions? For example, I now get ProductPrice from Products table, but I also want to get ProductStockQuantity from Stocks table. Is it possible to add 2 url: '@Url.Action("GetPrice")', and url: '@Url.Action("GetQuantity")', inside FillPrice() function?

Comment: @degergio: You can make as many AJAX calls as you like.  Though it probably makes more sense to have only one AJAX call which returns all of the data you'll need.  Unless the second call depends upon the results of the first call, there's no need for the overhead of 2 calls.